# shell exec and mysql

Tags: php

I've written a script that will take a file of INSERT INTO statements and load into a database using the shell_exec function. It is working however, I am a little concerned that there is no return value that I can test. The manual says that shell_exec returns what the command it runs returns which, in the case of `mysql`, is null.

Is there any other way to load a batch file of INSERT INTO statements other than with shell_exec? I'm open to anything that will work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using php it is possible to transfer the data to a file and from it using `mysql_query` which returns true if the query was succesful.

```
$tableName  = 'mypet';
$backupFile = 'mypet.sql';
$query      = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'backupFile' INTO TABLE $tableName";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Source: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The mysql client exits with status 1 if there was an error, and 0 if there was none. If you use exec() instead of shell_exec, you can have that exit status stored in a variable -- that way you'd be able to tell if something went wrong.